# Chrome Extension to check Component loading time For Angular 6

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular6

Hi My webpage takes too much time to load. I have installed Augury extension and able to get loaded component but in that it doesn't show loaded time.

So is there any Chrome Extensions or any software to track the loading time.

Comment: Use [devtools profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/).

Comment: @wOxxOm but i was not showing component loading time.

Comment: Ah, sounds like [Profiling React Components with the User Timing API](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/profiling-react-components-with-the-user-timing-api).